# How can I replay the Gravitron?

Tags: vvvvvv

How can I replay the Gravitron from the game? I know about the Super Gravitron in the secret lab, but that's too hard to be fun.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To replay the second intermission

Play modes / Intermissions / Intermission 2